# Adding a weak ivar to a Objective-C class using the runtime

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, weak-references, objective-c-runtime

Is it possible to add a zeroing weak ref (in the ARC sense, not GC) instance variable to a class created using the runtime? If so how?

There is a function called `class_setWeakIvarLayout()` which seems to be related to this but the documentation (both for this function and the non-weak counterpart) is *very* thin unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`class_setWeakIvarLayout()` is used under GC.   I'm not sure it is used under ARC at all.   In any case, you can't change the layout of a class at runtime, including adding arbitrary instance variables (though you can add ivars to a class and recompile without recompiling subclasses because of the modern runtime).

See Associated objects.   They provide most of what you want, maybe all (I'm not sure if zeroing-weak is supported directly -- not, you'll need to find an alternative solution).

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocAssociativeReferences.html

---

Ahh -- OK.   Thanks for the clarification.   I'm not sure if you can dynamically set the zeroing-weak ARC behaviors via API.  The source for the runtime and compiler are available, though.

Note that you can pretty easily fake zeroing weak under non-ARC environments by setting up a class that implements -dealloc to do whatever cleanup you need, associating instances with objects that need to trigger said cleanup on deallocation and making sure nothing else retains the object that has the custom -dealloc notification hook.  It is a bit fragile, but it works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am aware that you cannot change a class after registering it. This is intended for a completely custom class created using objc_allocateClassPair(). Sadly OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN is only weak and not zeroing weak (tested using a small exercise), so I was actually trying to find an alternative solution by adding an ivar :)

Comment: @frenetischapplaudierend: Further to bbum's last paragraph, Mike Ash has [an article about creating your own zeroing weak references](http://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-07-16-zeroing-weak-references-in-objective-c.html) which may interest you.

Comment: Josh and bbum, thanks for your help. For now I'll probably stay with just an associated object, until it becomes a problem with the non-zeroing weak ref. Just hoped there was an easy way to do it correctly. Will take a look at Mike Ashs implementation though, it looks promising!

Comment: Ok, I got curious and searched around in the objc runtime source as suggested by bbum. And it turns out you can make your own __weak ivars. Key is the class_setWeakIvarLayout() function, but the documentation to it is severely lacking, even in the source code. I'm gonna try and explain it in an answer.

Comment: Ok, next time more research before getting excited... While class_setWeakIvarLayout() seems to be consulted for ARR classes during object_setIvar(), there is a check before if the class was compiled with ARR enabled. This test will fail for classes added via runtime functions, so still back to where I was...

Comment: Instead of associated objects you could use `NSMapTable` to hold weak references where the keys are the "source" objects (the instances that you're planning to attach the associated object) and the values are your "target" objects.

Answer (score 9):

You can achieve a **zeroing** weak reference using associative references with a container class.  Basically:

1. Your container class contains a single ivar, which is declared `__weak id`
2. The associative reference 'setter' creates a conatiner, sets the `__weak id` ivar to point to your object, and then stores the container using `objc_setAssociatedObjects(self,&key,container,OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)`
3. Your getter retrieves the container using `objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &key)` and returns the `__weak id` ivar.  If your object has been `dealloc`'ed, the `__weak id ivar` of the container will be zero.

Comment: Shouldn't `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN` be `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN` if you want a weak reference?

Comment: This looks quite nice when container is NSProxy subclass.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569840/using-objc-setassociatedobject-with-weak-references/27035233#27035233 which has example code.