# Using objc_setAssociatedObject with weak references

Tags: objective-c, weak-references, objective-c-runtime

I know that OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN exists, but does it zero the reference if the target object is dealloced?  Or is it like the old days where that reference needs to get nil-ed or we risk a bad access later on?

Comment: Yeah, true.  I'll try it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After trying it out, the answer is NO.

I ran the following code under the iOS 6 Simulator, but it would probably have the same behavior with previous iterations of the runtime:

```
NSObject *test1 = [NSObject new];

NSObject __weak *test2 = test1;

objc_setAssociatedObject(self, "test", test1, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN);

test1 = nil;

id test3 = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, "test");
```

In the end, test1 and test2 are nil, and test3 is the pointer previously stored into test1.  Using test3 would result in trying to access an object that had already been dealloced.

Comment: Typo in there?  how is "test1" related to "test" and "test2"?

Answer (score 34):

As ultramiraculous demonstrated, `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN` does not do zeroing weak reference and you risk to access a deallocated object. But it’s quite easy to implement yourself. You just need a simple class to wrap an object with a weak reference:

```
@interface WeakObjectContainer : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, readonly, weak) id object;
@end

@implementation WeakObjectContainer
- (instancetype) initWithObject:(id)object
{
    if (!(self = [super init]))
        return nil;

    _object = object;

    return self;
}
@end
```

Then you must associate the `WeakObjectContainer` as OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN(_NONATOMIC):

```
objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &MyKey, [[WeakObjectContainer alloc] initWithObject:object], OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
```

and use the `object` property to access it in order to get a zeroing weak reference:

```
id object = [objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &MyKey) object];
```

Comment: Why not just use NSValue::valueWithNonretainedObject: ?

Comment: Because `-[NSValue nonretainedObjectValue]` does not return a *weak* object and thus does not do zeroing weak reference.

Comment: Cool but minor concern: The WeakObjectContainer itself object is still retained, meaning leaked. The target object might very well be collected and the reference zeroed out but the wrapper sticks around.

Comment: Associated objects are automatically [deallocated when their owner is deallocated](https://github.com/aosm/objc4/blob/345130a19b83510b81277864a79226111b9da3ea/runtime/objc-runtime-new.mm#L6825).

Answer (score 13):

One more option similar to `WeakObjectContainer`:

```
- (id)weakObject {
    id (^block)(void) = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(weakObject));
    return (block ? block() : nil);
}

- (void)setWeakObject:(id)object {
    id __weak weakObject = object;
    id (^block)(void) = ^{ return weakObject; };
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(weakObject),
                             block, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY);
}
```

Comment: Nice solution that eliminates having to create a wrapper class of your own. Thanks!

Comment: The block should annotate its return value as `_Nullable`.

Answer (score 1):

Swift version of answer by 0xced (with type support):

```
public class WeakObjectContainer<T: AnyObject>: NSObject {

    private weak var _object: T?

    public var object: T? {
        return _object
    }

    public init(with object: T?) {
        _object = object
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This behavior isn't specified in the docs or headers as best I can tell, so it's likely an implementation detail that you shouldn't count on, even if you were able to discern what the current behavior is.  I would guess that it is *not* zeroed out.  Here's why:

In general, there is no need to `nil` out references in iVars during `-dealloc`. If an object is dealloced, it shouldn't matter if its iVars were zeroed out, because any further accessing of the dealloced object or its iVars is, in and of itself, a programming error. In fact, I've heard some argue that it's better to **not** clear out references during `-dealloc`, because it will make erroneous accesses *more* obvious/expose bugs sooner.

EDIT: Oh, I guess I misread your question. You want "zeroing weak references". Associated storage doesn't appear to support those.  You could make a trivial pass-through class with one ivar/property marked as __weak and achieve the same effect that way. A little kludgey, but it'd work.

Comment: I mean in the case I'm looking at, it's not a erroneous if I try to access the object after it's dealloced.  If I have a weak reference, like a reference to a delegate, I'm expecting that it might not exist anymore by the time I message it.

Answer (score 0):

In case people still need a workaround for this, here is a solution in Swift to replace the normal `objc_getAssociatedObject` with a custom one to handle weak objects:

```swift
func objc_getAssociatedWeakObject(_ object: AnyObject, _ key: UnsafeRawPointer) -> AnyObject? {
    let block: (() -> AnyObject?)? = objc_getAssociatedObject(object, key) as? (() -> AnyObject?)
    return block != nil ? block?() : nil
}

func objc_setAssociatedWeakObject(_ object: AnyObject, _ key: UnsafeRawPointer, _ value: AnyObject?) {
    weak var weakValue = value
    let block: (() -> AnyObject?)? = {
        return weakValue
    }
    objc_setAssociatedObject(object, key, block, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY)
}
```