# Using a Delegate in a Category

Tags: objective-c, delegates, objective-c-category

I've created a category with 2 properties but I'm having an issue trying to use one as a delegate.

```
    //  UIView+Dropdown.h
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

   @protocol DropDownAnimationDoneDelegate <NSObject>
    -(void) onDropDownAnimationDone:(id)sender;
    @end

    @interface UIView (Dropdown)
    @property (strong, nonatomic) id <DropDownAnimationDoneDelegate> delegateForDropDown;
    @property (nonatomic,assign) BOOL isDropped;

    //  UIView+Dropdown.m
    #import "UIView+Dropdown.h"
    #import <objc/runtime.h>

    @implementation UIView (Dropdown)
    -(void)setDelegateForDropDown:(id)ddDelegate{
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(delegateForDropDown),ddDelegate,OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);}

    -(id)delegateForDropDown{
        return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(delegateForDropDown));}

    -(void)setIsDropped:(BOOL)dropIt{
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(isDropped), [NSNumber numberWithBool:dropIt], OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);}

    -(BOOL)isDropped{
        return [objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(isDropped)) boolValue];}
```

The delegate will be used for notification after an animation block is complete:

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.75
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{self.center = newCenter;}
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         if ([[self delegateForDropDown] respondsToSelector:@selector(onDropDownAnimationDone:)])
                         [[self delegateForDropDown] onDropDownAnimationDone:self];}];
```

My problem is `delegateForDropDown` always contains `nil`.
The boolean property works fine so I suspect it has someting to do with the delegate's type being id

Comment: What are you even trying to achieve using that associated object hackage at all?

Comment: I created a view subclass that behaves like a dropdown list. Now I want to use the animation behavior on other views (like a UIButton) so I decided to create a category to use on any view. I have everything working except for the notificated of the completion of the animation.

Comment: you dont show any code setting delegateForDropdown on self.  but I presume you are doing this?

Comment: `delegateForDropdown` property is set by the calling class to `self`. The class then calls a method containing the animation code shown above. The debugger is showing a valid object `id` being pass into `setDelegateForDropDown` but `objc_setAssociatedObject` doesn't appear to be saving the value. The getter reurns `nil`. Setting and getting the other property (isDropped) works fine.

Comment: After reading this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569840/using-objc-setassociatedobject-with-weak-references) I think I need to change the parameter to `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN`

Comment: Found the problem. Programming error on my part. I was setting the delegate property for the wrong view. It works fine now. TomSwift pointed me in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. Programming error on my part. I was setting the delegate property for the wrong view so the problem was in the calling class. It works fine now. TomSwift pointed me in the right direction. Thanks.